# Creating weight raster for flow accumulation in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, hydrology, arc-hydro, flood, flow-accumulation

I am studying flood flow using ArcGIS for Desktop.

When creating flow accumulation in hydrology, there is a weight raster.

However, İf you do not have it, the programme sets its value to 1 which is not a suitable approximation for the simulations.

How can I create a weight raster in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is probably a little late, but hopefully better than never.  William Huber came up with an answer a couple years ago and I implemented it as a model in Model Builder.

See the following tool - http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=40d33968c44e4c9395c9c1ff1edd2bbe

and blog post - 
http://gislandscapeecology.blogspot.com/2015/04/better-flow-accumulation-with-positive.html